# ERROR:22PO2 in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COALESCE(REPLACE(substr(c.abc,strpos(c.abc,':')),':',''),'0') from book C
```

Here in the above query the column `abc` contains values as "21:34" / "text" which is in the character varying which has to be converted to `BIGINT`.
The above query is just converting small length of string but it's not converting bigger length of string.

I know that a regular expression can be used but unable to do implementation as I'm new to this.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: If you want the first number converted: `split_part(abc,':',1)::int` if you want the second number converted: `split_part(abc,':',2)::int`